# Is it possible to get the list of google blacklisted domains?

Tags: blacklist, safe-browsing

I know that browsers use Google safe browsing service to detect if a domain is blacklisted or not. The client(for example Firefox) basically downloads a **hashed** list of these domains and then checks if a url is blacklisted or not. My question is that, is it possible to access this list of domains?(not their hash values which is not reversible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in a company in which we were doing web filtering. We were doing also category based filtering like not allow gambling websites or adult etc..

I didn't see open version of Google safe browsing urls when I were working . Instead we had several sources but best free source was as I remember http://www.urlblacklist.com/ . Which has like 1.5 million websites categorized.You can filter out urls under categories like Adult-Gambling etc....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you only asking for the Google blacklist, but since Kafka Erdem Damir suggested another list, a few friends of mine used the "shallalist". Unfortunately it's a German service. 
http://www.shallalist.de